# CSS transition fade effect on sub-menus not working

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition, fade, submenu

I'm trying to build some sub-menus with fade in/out effects. Each sub-menu should fade in when the mouse hovers over the corresponding parent menu item. Here's my code so far:

```
.navbar ul ul {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -99999px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity .1s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity .1s linear;
    transition: opacity .1s linear;
}

.navbar li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.35s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.35s ease;
}
```

**The Problem:**

The sub-menu's fade effect does not work. When I hover my mouse over any parent item, the corresponding sub-menu displays instantly without the fade in/out effect.

**The Solution (thanks to Cam):**

```
.navbar ul ul {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in;
}

.navbar li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition:     opacity 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition:        opacity 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition:          opacity 0.35s ease;
    transition:             opacity 0.35s ease;
}
```

Comment: .1s is really fast. I would try .5s on both the in and out.  Also start with ease-in not linear.

Comment: ALso change to visibility and dont do display: none. That should fix that.

Comment: remove visibility and  display  , opacity is already doing the job and have a numerical value that can be increased/decreased ( 0.00 to 1.00 )